# Isn't there a way to use chrome.proxy in chrome packaged apps?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I have to control a Webview with changing http-proxy,
but Chrome doesn't support chrome.proxy for packaged apps.

It's allowed to use chrome.proxy in legacy packaged apps but, the legacy packaged apps don't include the Webview.

It seems possible to switch proxy via tcp server-client connection with other windows programs that can switch proxy-setting fundamentally, but I don't want to run programs separately.

Isn't there a way to control proxy in only chrome packaged apps?

---

'proxy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.